# como puedo usar el this en angular al trabajar con jquery en los componentes

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, tablas

[image: En este apartado se muestra que no reconoce el this de la tabla]

lo intenté en el index.html exactamente igual y si funciona, ayudaaa!!

```
      $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function () {
      var pk = $(this).eq(0).html();
      alert(pk);
      });
```

Comment: Estaría bien que indicaras que error te devuelve!

Comment: Importante: No uses JQuery con Angular.